# How to add stylesheet into wordpress for a website converting html to wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-shortcode

How to add a stylesheet into WordPress for a website converting HTML to WordPress?

Link of the stylesheet in HTML head.

```
<link data-minify="1" rel='stylesheet' id='fontAweasome-css'  href='wp-content/themes/lacomparaison/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

```
<link data-minify="1" rel='stylesheet' id='ft-header-style-css'  href='wp-content/themes/lacomparaison/css/header/header.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In the `function.php` code link the stylesheet.

```
<?php
function add_css() {
    wp_register_style( 'ft-header-style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/themes/firstguide/css/header/header.css', false, '1.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ft-header-style-css' );

    wp_register_style( 'fontAweasome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/wp-content/themes/firstguide/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css', false, '1.1', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontAweasome-css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css' );
```

code in `header.php` to link the stylesheet

adding `<?php wp_head(); ?>` just before

I am converting HTML to WordPress on localhost XAMPP but css file not linking to the header.

Comment: In my case enqueue method not working but this is <link data-minify="1" rel='stylesheet' id='fontAweasome-css'  href='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css' type='text/css' media='all' /> working. I have more than 28 stylesheet and want to add using enqueue method but correcting path in enqueue still not working

Comment: file name was function.php after rename to functions.php working fine

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your header file looks fine. But you seemed to be using the url path wrong. I changed the url.

*Before*:

> /wp-content/themes/firstguide/css/header/header.css

*After:*

> /firstguide/css/header/header.css

Same goes for other one.

Here's the code you can use on your ***function.php*** page

```
function add_css(){
wp_register_style('ft-header-style-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/firstguide/css/header/header.css', false,'1.1','all');
wp_register_style('fontAweasome-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/firstguide/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css', false,'1.1','all');


wp_enqueue_style('ft-header-style-css') ;
wp_enqueue_style('fontAweasome-css') ;

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css') ;
```

Comment: enqueue method not working but this is working <link data-minify="1" rel='stylesheet' id='fontAweasome-css'  href='<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/fonts/fontawesome/css/all.css' type='text/css' media='all' />

Comment: Naimur Rahman if `firstguide` is the theme name then you don't have to write it, `get_template_directory_uri()` will give you the parent theme name as well.